# Wrangle data in R to add variables (columns) and observations (rows) by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to rearrange a dataset with a few thousand observations (to eventually use the drm function in package DRC), and I am tired of doing it in excel. Within a dataframe I am looking to add "start" and "end" times (up to inf) based on the intervals found in a vector within the df. This means I would have to end up adding an observation (row) where there the last "end" time is inf. For that last row (the one with inf) I ALSO need to subtract the total of "value" from an arbitrary number (in my example below this would be 50). All this grouped by two variables ("Name", and "Rep" in my example). I am hoping there is a solution using `group_by`, but honestly I'll be overjoyed at any solution!

I have a data set that looks like this;

```
# data
names<-c(rep("Luke",30), rep("Han", 30), rep("Leia", 30), rep("OB1", 30))
reps<-c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10))
time<-rep(seq(1:10), 4)
value<-rep(sample(0:5,10,replace=T), 4)
df<-data.frame(names, reps, time, value)
```

but need it to look like this;
Example of the data structure I need.

[image]

I'm at a loss. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
          group_by(names, reps) %>%
          mutate(start = lag(time, default = 0), 
                 end = time) 

bind_rows(df1, df1 %>%
                 group_by(names, reps) %>%
                 summarise(start = last(time), 
                            end = Inf, 
                            value = sum(value))) %>%
                 select(-time) %>%
                 arrange(names, reps) 


#  names reps  value start   end
#   <fct> <fct> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Han   A         2     0     1
# 2 Han   A         2     1     2
# 3 Han   A         1     2     3
# 4 Han   A         1     3     4
# 5 Han   A         3     4     5
# 6 Han   A         2     5     6
# 7 Han   A         0     6     7
# 8 Han   A         2     7     8
# 9 Han   A         2     8     9
#10 Han   A         5     9    10
#11 Han   A        20    10   Inf
#.....
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak Shaw! I am getting the following error; `Error in select(., -time) : unused argument (-time)` Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Dustin most probably that is because there is conflict in using `select`. Try restarting R or explicitly use `dplyr::select(-time)` instead of `select(-time)`

Comment: yes that was issue, thank you. This is working perfectly on my real dataset as well! The only change I made was adding "50-" in front of "value = sum(value) so that the line reads,  `50 - value = sum(value)`. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `data.table` `shift`ing the 'time' while appending 'Inf' at the end of 'time' to create the `end` and difference of 50 from the `sum` of 'value' for 'value' after grouping by 'names' and 'reps'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  {stL <-  last(time)
              enL <- Inf
             vL <- 50- sum(value)
        .(start = c(shift(time, fill = 0), stL), 
          end = c(time, enL), 
          value = c(value, vL))}, .(names, reps)]
#     names reps start end value
#  1:  Luke    A     0   1     0
#  2:  Luke    A     1   2     3
#  3:  Luke    A     2   3     3
#  4:  Luke    A     3   4     4
#  5:  Luke    A     4   5     0
# ---                           
#128:   OB1    C     6   7     3
#129:   OB1    C     7   8     0
#130:   OB1    C     8   9     2
#131:   OB1    C     9  10     5
#132:   OB1    C    10 Inf    27
```